# Magento 2 - Customising Forgot Password email template: How do I overwrite the forgot password email template? Where is it?

Tags: magento2, email, frontend

I want to customize the Forgot Password email template. In the admin panel I see it

[image]

But in the in the module folder there doesn't appear to be a corresponding template

[image]

What is the name of the file so I can overwrite it in my theme?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Magento didn't add a config setting to override the default template like they have for all other templates. In this case you'll need to copy `vendors/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/email/change_email.html` to your custom theme (`app/design/frontend/PackageName/ThemeName/Magento_Customer/email/change_email.html`).